# air push adview error

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, airpush

I am embeding air push ads in my android app. I added adview in layout.xml file. It has errors that are

```
      Multiple annotations found at this line:
  - error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'canShowMR' in package 'com.GUI.traficsing'
- error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'banner_type' in package 'com.GUI.traficsing'
- error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'placementType' in package 'com.GUI.traficsing'
- error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'refresh_time' in package 'com.GUI.traficsing'
- error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'animation' in package 'com.GUI.traficsing'
- error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'test_mode' in package 'com.GUI.traficsing'
```

Thank you

Comment: Have you solved it ? I am facing the same problem

Comment: You may want to reconsider using air push ads. Aside from the well deserved hatemail you'll get, Google just changed their policy in regards to them. http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2013/08/no-more-notification-ads-and-icon-ads.html

Answer (score 9):

You need to place the `mraid_attrs.xml` file into your app's `res > values` folder. This file is included within the SDK download.

It solved me the same problem.

Ref: http://manage.airpush.com/docs/index.php?title=Android_SDK_6.0_Documentation